# Receive file remotely for data analysis

Tags: file-transfer

I need to get files with data to run my own program for each file or bunch of files.
What is the best way to receive those files?

Do I need to set up my own server that expose API for file upload?
Should I use S3 and set up a server that fetch files from it automatically? or Maybe DropBox?
Or should I use SFTP server?
The amount of files are not big (max 1Giga per day)

I'm using Spring boot for my own server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using SFTP, you can listen to changes (e.g. file upload) in a remote directory by connecting a listener. SFTP, in my opinion, is a great choice for file integration.

You said you will be using Spring Boot. Spring has a project called **[Spring Integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/index.html)**, which has SFTP support.

Spring Boot has a starter called `spring-boot-starter-integration` useful for bringing the best suited Spring Integration versions to your Spring Boot project. Spring Integration SFTP is really easy to use, since a lot of abstraction is provided by the framework.